# gpg encryption failed: file open error

Tags: php, gnupg

I have been going nuts with this..

I have gnupg installed on my CentOS server and I try to encrypt uploaded files (uploaded via a PHP page). On the server via the command line, it works perfectly. But via the php script, it fails with this error:

```
gpg: /path-to-my-file/my-file: encryption failed: file open error
```

The user apache (which I think is used to run the exec command) has read/write in the directory of the file.

The file is uploaded fine (I can see it afterward as I removed the deletion of the unencrypted file from my code) and can be deleted correctly via the php site.

the command I run is the following

```
/path-to-gpg/gpg --homedir=/path-to-my-home-gnupg/.gnupg -e -r therecipient@email the-unencrypted-file
```

Any idea how I could tackle this?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to check:

- Run `system("ls " . escapeshellarg($file))` and check the result — is it file not found? Permission denied? That will help you debug.
- Run `system("whoami")` to make sure PHP is running as who you think it is.
- Run `echo "<pre>ls " . escapeshellarg($file) . "</pre>"` then copy+paste the command and run it from the shell to make sure that the path to the file is what you expected it to be.

Also, I believe CentOS runs SELinux by default… If you've got it installed, check the logs (in `/var/log/`) to see if SELinux is preventing Apache from executing GPG.

Comment: let me check all this and come back with results

Comment: the file was there. I was running as apache.. but the error log was actually very helpful so thanks for pointing it out. I found out that my pubring and secring where actually owned by root and not by apache. As a consequence apache could not read them and could not encrypt the file. changing ownership to apache solved the issue. thanks david

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command with actual apache user privileges in verbose mode:

```
su apache -c /path-to-gpg/gpg -vv ...
```